# WPF Styles Question

Tags: wpf, styles

A simple question which I can't find the answer on the web for some reason...

I want to place the content to a ResourceDictionary:

```
<TextBlock
    Style="{StaticResource HomePageTextStyle}">
    <LineBreak/>
    Hello<LineBreak/>
    <Bold>World!</Bold>
    <LineBreak/>
</TextBlock>
```

The best I could do was:

```
<s:String x:Key="HomePageTextContent">
    Hello World!
</s:String>
```

Which stripped all the formatting from the content :( Help please~ Thanks in advance. Oh, and If you can recommend a nice reference for using WPF Styles, it would be great~ Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you want to use data-binding instead of applying a style, since you are putting content in the TextBlock not changing the appearance of the TextBlock itself, e.g. drawing a border around it.
According to MSDN: TextBlock supports the hosting and display of [Inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.aspx) flow content elements. To be more precise, the content of the TextBlock in your first code block becomes a [InlineCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines(VS.96).aspx) in the Inlines property of the TextBlock. Unfortunately the Inlines property isn't a dependency property so we can't bind data to it. The Text property, on the other hand, is a dependency property but doesn't allow anything other than a String.

To make a long story short, I don't think you can achieve what you want using pure XAML.

Comment: Actually, I'm using it for localization purposes~ :(